# Why does Caliburn.Micro call PropertyChanged

Tags: caliburn.micro

I've a class which does not have a base class nor implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
In my application one object of this class is used as the viewmodel for 2 views (master and detail).

If I create the bindings to the properties by convention (x:Name). I see that when I change a property in the detail view it is also updated in the master.
This does not happen when I use the normal binding syntax.

Can anyone explain me why this happens ? Is this a feature of Caliburn.Micro ? I couldn't find it in the documents.

=== edit ==

I just found out that when using normal binding that the other view also get's updated only after the text box loses focus.
Still the question remains how can a View react to a change in the viewmodel when propertychanged is not implemented.

Thanks in advance,
Marwijn.

Comment: Are those properties normal CLR properties or Dependency Properties ?

Comment: Normal CLR properties.

Comment: Can you post the XAML code for the master and detail view ?

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn.Micro binds properties with `BindingMode.TwoWay` by default. 
If you did not specify this explicitly in your own binding - you've used `OneWay`.

Comment: The problem (or suprise) is not that values dont get updated, I'm suprised that both views get updated when I change a property without me implementing NotifyPropertyChanged.